# Class not found on namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm creating an API wrapper at the moment, and I decided to create an index.php which loads the Client, just for testing/debugging purposes.

Here's my index.php

```
require_once("src/API/Client.php");

$client = new \API\Client();
```

Here's my API\Client

```
namespace API;

class Client
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_requester = new Client\Request();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that API\Client\Request is not found in the Client.php

It does exist, and can be viewed below:

```
namespace API\Client

class Request
{
    protected $_requestUrl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

This is my first foray into making an application that has fully namespaced classes, so I'd appreciate your help in getting this working.

Comment: It also might be a good idea to inject `Request` instead of hard coding it in constructor: `$client = new \API\Client(new \API\Client\Request);`

Comment: write in constructor require_once 'src/API/Client/Request.php'; above $this->_requester = new Client\Request(); line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `require_once` statement to include the script that contains the `Request` class definition.

```
require_once("src/API/Client.php");
require_once("src/API/Client/Request.php"); // <-- or whatever the filename is
```

I recommend using an autoloader which means you don't need any include statements. For example this [PSR-0 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/).

Also, your use of the `return` statement in the constructors serves no purpose. Constructors can't return values.

Comment: I used an autoloader combined with a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`to get all the files autoloaded. Thanks for your help.